# How can I call Kotlin classes that are in flavor specific folders in Android Studio from Java without using the flavor on the method call?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

So I have some flavors on my gradle file. I have some things that only run when they are on those flavors. Typically I will have the same class on all flavors but only some of the flavors will do something when called.

When I converted those flavor classes to Kotlin, the calls from Java got weird. For example:

```
    KotlinClass.INSTANCE.initSomeStuff$app_flavor1Debug();
```

So when I change flavors not I have to change `app_flavor1Debug` to whatever the other flavor is. When this code was just java it should be `JavaClass.initSomeStuff();`.

How can I make it so I don't have to do that? there must be some sort of alias or something I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: It will be decompiled in that way only. However, you can change that manually and try to run it. Just if some code is in main and flavor specific code both, remove that. If you want that code should have an entry point from main only. You need to create the instance of the same class with different operation accordingly.

Comment: What I do right now is have a little Java wrapper on each flavor that makes those calls, each flavor has their own `$app_flavorFlavorName` on that Java file. Seems like a really ugly solution. I thought there was a way to tell Kotlin to give Java aliases for certain stuff?

Comment: Hey. Can you please look at this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777585/unresolved-reference-for-java-file-in-a-different-flavor-when-referencing-from-k

I was thinking if we can use some sourceSets concept to fix your problem

Comment: This seems similar but not the same. I have no issue calling the code, I just have to use the flavor on the method name. Also they talk about package and directory conflicts, but I continued with the java way of doing packages, basically have a directory for each part of the package.